# Sending a paste command to a specific X11 window

Tags: linux, bash, xorg

I'm launching multiple instances of a game via bash. Each instance has it's own login password, which I can retrieve from my password manager, which will place it in the clipboard. I'd like to send each instance it's corresponding password and an "Enter" key event, to log them in automatically. The game runs inside a wine virtual desktop, and each instance has a unique window title in WM_NAME.

Any way I can automate the login process?

Answer (score 1):

try [`xte`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte) & [`wmctrl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) packages... Using wmctrl, you can focus any specific window & using xte, you can fake keystrokes.

1. Based on title, you can focus any window, using wmctrl.
2. They add some time delay, if required
3. Send keystrokes using xte

Check the man-pages for syntax.

Comment: Are there any alternatives? Sending keys vs trigger paste makes a difference if you paste to a eg terminal

Comment: You are right. Paste and typing are different. If you paste, the clipboard will be used. It is particularly different if the window in question is a VNC/remote desktop session to another system. In that case the clipboard of the remote system will be used. Plus many applications (or even web pages) block the paste operation. Or some applications just don't implement the paste operation.
If you particularly want to use 'paste', you can try sending keystrokes corresponding to paste (ctrl+v / ctrl+shift+v / shift+insert etc)